# When creating an SQL view, how do I add an array column that is a collection of records from a column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

For example, let's say I have a table for my users with the `username` column, and I have another table for user posts which has a many-to-one mapping of `usernames` to `post_ids`. I want to create a view of the two tables which has a column `username` and a column `posts` with an integer array `integer[]` of `post_ids` that this user has created. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
SELECT u.username, ARRAY_AGG(p.postid)
FROM usernames u INNER JOIN posts p ON u.username = p.username
GROUP BY u.username
```

Substitute in your table and column names, add any ordering you want, etc.

Comment: actually, you could even avoid the join if your table of posts has the username in it, so just `SELECT username, ARRAY_AGG(postid) FROM posts GROUP BY username`